# How Do I Get More Than 16TB Out Of EXT3?

Tags: raid, mdadm, ext3

I have an MDADM RAID 6 array that I just added a 20th disk to.  It consists of 20 1TB drives.

RAID Detail:

```
$ sudo mdadm --detail /dev/md0
[sudo] password for :
/dev/md0:
    Version : 00.90
    Creation Time : Fri Feb 12 12:36:20 2010
    Raid Level : raid6
    Array Size : 17581676544 (16767.19 GiB 18003.64 GB)
    Used Dev Size : 976759808 (931.51 GiB 1000.20 GB)
    Raid Devices : 20
    Total Devices : 20
    Preferred Minor : 0
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Sat Dec 14 14:45:57 2013
    State : clean
    Active Devices : 20
    Working Devices : 20
    Failed Devices : 0
    Spare Devices : 0

    Chunk Size : 512K
```

Kernel

```
$ uname -r
2.6.32-48-generic
```

The error I am running into:

```
$ sudo resize2fs /dev/md0
resize2fs 1.41.11 (14-Mar-2010)
resize2fs: File too large while trying to determine filesystem size
```

I am rapidly getting close to running out of room:

```
$ df
/dev/md0             16344351220 16277117492  67233728 100% /Media
```

How do I get past the 16TB threshold?  I do not have anything large enough to back up the data to at this point, nor is it financially feasible to do at this point.  It was never anticipated that it would have got this large in the beginning.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried considering ext4?

Comment: If there is a way to do it "online", that would be great.

Comment: @Go3Team yes but I'd be very cautious... it will take ages :X See if my answer suffices.

Comment: "I do not have anything large enough to back up the data to at this point, nor is it financially feasible to do at this point. It was never anticipated that it would have got this large in the beginning." This is going to get you into trouble... I would seriously consider making a backup before you do anything to the discs. A DAT tape drive can handle 16Gb. We are on 1.5 Tb with our discs by the way ;)

Comment: @Rinzwind The array is >16TB not GB.  My wife insists that I delete a few things.  I am such a pack rat, I'd rather not part with the media if I don't have to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that ext3 do not support more than 16 TiB using 4 KiB blocks. Either you chang the block size or transform the drive to ext4. Transforming can be done online, just changing the mountpoints and activating the options as shown in the [Ubuntu Help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ConvertFilesystemToExt4):

1. Edit your `/etc/fstab` file and change the `ext3` entry for `ext4`. **Reboot the system**.
2. Acctivate the options:

   ```
   sudo tune2fs -O extents,uninit_bg,dir_index /dev/sda1
   ```
3. If you installed grub in the same partition, you should reinstall it:

   ```
   sudo grub-install /dev/sda
   ```

Here is a table with the specific limit size of ext4 and ext3:

### [Ext3 Size limits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext3#Size_limits)

The max number of blocks for ext3 is 232. The size of a block can vary, affecting the max number of files and the max size of the file system:

```
Block size       Maximum         Maximum
                 file size       file system size
1 KiB            16 GiB          2 TiB
2 KiB            256 GiB         8 TiB
4 KiB            2 TiB           16 TiB
8 KiB            2 TiB           32 TiB
```

### [Ext4 Size limits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4#Features)

The ext4 filesystem can support volumes with sizes up to 1 exbibyte (EiB) and files with sizes up to 16 tebibytes (TiB). Volumes larger than 16 tebibytes (TiB) are not recommended.